# whereHas query in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Hello guys,

```
        $filterArray = explode("_", $filters);

        $data['articles'] = \DB::table('products')->join('product_category', function ($q) {
            $q->on('product_category.product_id', '=', 'products.id');
        })->where('product_category.category_id', '=', $id)
            ->select('products.*')
            ->whereBetween('price_retail_1', array($priceFrom, $priceTo))
            ->whereHas('filters', function ($query, $filterArray) {
                $query->whereIn('filter_id', $filterArray);
            })
            ->orderBy('products.' . $sort, $sortOrder)
            ->get();
    }
```

I have the following query and I'm having some issues on the whereHas method. I'm getting an error

```
Unknown column 'has' in 'where clause
```

most likely because the $filterArray variable is out of scope for the function ( or at least that is what I am guessing. Any help on how to solve the issue is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use `whereHas` method in the Query Builder context. The `whereHas` method is only for **Eloquent** Query Builder that is comming from the Eloquent models and their relationships.

What you can do is to use `joins`. So you can try like this:

```
$filterArray = explode("_", $filters);

$data['articles'] = \DB::table('products')->join('product_category', function ($q) {
        $q->on('product_category.product_id', '=', 'products.id');
    })->where('product_category.category_id', '=', $id)
        ->select('products.*')
        ->whereBetween('price_retail_1', array($priceFrom, $priceTo))
        ->join('filters', 'products.filter_id', '=', 'filters.filter_id')
        ->whereIn('filter_id', $filterArray);
        ->orderBy('products.' . $sort, $sortOrder)
        ->get();
```

I don't know how you connecting these two tables so here is only the example data:

```
->join('filters', 'products.filter_id', '=', 'filters.filter_id')
```

Comment: Mind giving me an example? Because the filters table can contain multiple rows of the same product, I need to do a OR WHERE search based on the data given in the filters array.