# how to get Laravel query builder results same as ORM

Tags: laravel, orm, laravel-query-builder

Hope you are doing well.
I want Query builder results same as ORM.
My Orm Query is

```
       $categories=Category::where("language_id",$lang->id)
        ->whereHas('blogs')
        ->with(['blogs'=>function($query){
            $query->latest();
        }])->get();
```

It shows the perfect results I want.
My Query Builder Query is

```
$data=DB::table('categories')
        ->select('categories.id','categories.title','blogs.category_id',
            DB::raw('COUNT(DISTINCT blogs.id) as totalblogs')
        )
        ->join('blogs','categories.id','=','blogs.category_id')
        ->groupBy('categories.id')
        ->get();
```

it shows each blog with category repetetion with each blog. I want results same as ORM gives. How can i achieve this. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Get help from this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39711486/wherehas-query-in-laravel#:~:text=You%20cannot%20use%20whereHas%20method%20in%20the%20Query%20Builder%20context.

Comment: It seems you for forgot adding the where() method in the query builder.